# Want to add a Column as "PercentOfRise %" In this query

Tags: mysql, sql

```
(SELECT EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID, FirstName, Lastname,JobTitle, Salary,
CASE 
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Data Analyst' THEN Salary + (Salary * 0.20)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant' THEN Salary + (Salary * 0.15)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'HR' THEN Salary + (Salary * 0.02)
    ELSE Salary + (Salary * 0.10)
END AS SalaryAfterRaise
FROM EmployeeDemographics 
INNER JOIN EmployeeSalary ON 
    EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID)
```

[This is what the table looks like after this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ATXcK.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can repeat the `case` expression:

```
(CASE WHEN JobTitle = 'Data Analyst' THEN 0.20
      WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant' THEN 0.15
      WHEN JobTitle = 'HR' THEN 0.02
      ELSE 0.10
 END) as RaiseRatio
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have salary raise based on your code. Now you need to divide that with
the salary and multiply it by 100 to get % increase

```
with new_salary as (

SELECT EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID, FirstName, Lastname,JobTitle, Salary,
CASE 
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Data Analyst' THEN Salary + (Salary * 0.20)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'Accountant' THEN Salary + (Salary * 0.15)
    WHEN JobTitle = 'HR' THEN Salary + (Salary * 0.02)
    ELSE Salary + (Salary * 0.10)
END AS SalaryAfterRaise
FROM EmployeeDemographics 
INNER JOIN EmployeeSalary ON 
    EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID = EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID
)

select 
* ,
(new_salary.SalaryAfterRaise - new_salary.salary  / new_salary.salary) * 100 as percent_increase
from new_salary
```